# jQuery ui drag disable on video dragbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jQuery UI for making divs draggable. Within one div is a Video Flow Player.

If you try to use the time drag bar the whole div is dragged. Is there a way to disable dragging when visitors using the video control bar?

Find a Fiddle with my [problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/yXqEV/).

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

Thanks!

T book

Comment: Only by dragging the bar ot the entire video? Is reasonable to drag the div using the yellow area under it?

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with overlaying a handle, but it doesn't seem to work where it overlaps the video object. You may not be able to avoid using a handle that extends outside the video:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yXqEV/4/

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="draggable_handle"></div>
    ...

$("#draggable").draggable({
     handle: "#draggable_handle"
 });
```